# attribute directive not working for ajax loaded element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, zend-framework2

I'm dealing with legacy code. My page is composed of three partial views, one for header, one for footer, one for the content. I have this element with `my-directive` in my footer:

```
<a my-directive>
    <img>
</a>
```

My footer is rendered at the same time with the others on page load. However, in my header, I have `#products_menu` whose content is loaded via ajax:

```
// calls a route to do some processing before returning the view
// to be rendered inside #products_menu
$('#products_menu').load(...);
```

`#products_menu` contains the same element with the same directive:

```
<a my-directive>
    <img>
</a>
```

This is my directive:

```
angular
    .module('module1')
        .directive('myDirective', ['$rootScope', 'ModalService', '$compile',
            function($rootScope, ModalService, $compile) {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                        console.log(element);

                        element.on('click', function(e) {...}
                     } ...
```

The problem is when I click on the element in the footer, it fires. But when I click on the element in the header, it doesn't. I'm assuming it's because the element was loaded dynamically, and the attribute was not bound during the time angular was compiling.

AM I right in my assumption and if so, is there a workaround?

Comment: Which types of elements are created in footer ?

Comment: @MayankVadiya mostly just anchor tags inside divs

Comment: I think you try like `<a href="javascript:void(0)>name</a>"`.. Means add `javascript:void(0)` into your `href`.

Comment: @MayankVadiya I'm not sure if that will work, the other anchor elements rendered normally work fine without that

Answer (score 0):

So just dumping the html via using jquery or DOM manipulation would not intimate angular to do its work. You have to tell angular about this or better compile the DOM using `$compile` service. Angular things will automatically triggers in for that template

```
$('#products_menu').load(..., function() {
   $compile($('#products_menu'))($scope);
})
```

I'd recommend to mix jQuery with angular, best way to handle this in angular way is using `ng-include` directive

```
<div id="products_menu" ng-include="'template.html'">
</div>
```